# Combine 2 has_many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many

Is it possible in rails to combine 2 has_many relations, so i can order the associations by positions.

I've already tried this:

```
has_many :paragraphs
has_many :images

def items
   (self.paragraphs + self.images)
end
```

But then it isn't possible to order the objects by position.
Is there a method, that i can use, so it would be:
has_many :items, (combine here the 2 has_many relations).order(:position)

Thankyou!

**Update**

Here's my complete setup:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :containers
end

class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paragraphs, -> { order(:position) }, class_name: 'Content::Paragraph'
  has_many :images, -> { order(:position) }, class_name: 'Content::Image'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paragraphs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

  def items
    items = self.paragraphs + self.images
  end
end

class Content::Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container, class_name: 'Container'
end

class Content::Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container, class_name: 'Container'
end
```

An container belongs to an page.

I want to show on a page all the items, so paragraphs + images and sort them by position.
Also the most Acts_as_list -ish gems are usable for single models and not for multiple models (my case). I think i need a parent model (reversed polymorphic association?) to easily get all the belonging items in correct order.

Example

```
Container:
  - Alinea (position 1)
  - Image (position 2)
  - Alinea (position 3)
```

Comment: Maybe you will want to use [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), so your model will have just one `has_many` association, and two model Paragraph and Image will belongs to that model. So you can get all paragraphs and images

Comment: @KienThanh could you give an example? I can only find polymorphic examples for a model that belongs to 2 other models, like comments. I'm looking for 2 models who belongs to 1 model.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand your question. Does your Paragraph and Image models have same attributes/columns? Why do you need to separate it to 2 models then you want get all in one association?

Comment: The Paragraph and Image model have different attributes, because in the Paragraph model is only the content attribute stored, but in the Image model there is also an file and alignment attribute stored. I'm building an cmd and want to show all paragraphs and images belonging to that page in correct order. So an image can be shown above an paragraph. I hope my question is now a bit more clear.

Comment: I think it has a bit complex, it means the number of images must be equal to the number of paragraph, right? and every image just has one paragraph below?

Comment: Ehm.. its very flexible.
[see image](http://oi62.tinypic.com/1j14cm.jpg)
So the user can change manually the order of the different objects. And i want to combine the 2 associations so i can put an order by position on the items.

Comment: well, it is not simple, to do that i think you have to do more work than just get associations like that because you need to change the order. currently i have not thought a solution for this yet.

Comment: It's indeed an complex problem, i've updated my question. Thanks for your help for so far!!